# How to fix weird issue with iconv on Mac Os x

Tags: macos, shell, iconv

I am on **Mac Os X** 10.5 (but I reproduced the issue on 10.4)

I am trying to use **iconv** to convert an **UTF-8 file to ASCII**

the utf-8 file contains characters like 'éàç'

I want the accented characters to be turned into their closest ascii equivalent

so

my **command** is this :

**iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE myutf8file.txt**

*which works fine on a Linux machine*

but on my local Mac Os X I get this for instance :

**è => 'e**

**à => `a**

I really dont undersatnd why iconv returns this weird output on mac os x but all is fine on linux

any help ? or directions ?

thanks in advance

Comment: what is the output you get on linux?

Comment: and what do you find weird about the mac output? are you using the apple-supplied iconv or installed it through macports, compiled it yourself, anything else?

Comment: hi

on linux : é => e, à => a

Comment: I am using the supplied iconv Or the MAMP supplied iconv

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that Mac OSX uses another implementation of iconv called libiconv. Most Linux distributions have an implementation of iconv which is part of libc. Unfortunately libiconv transliterates characters such as ö, è and ñ as "o, `e and ~n. The only way to fix this is to download the source and modify the translit.h file in the lib directory. Find lines that look like this:

2, '"', 'o',

and replace them with something like this:

1, 'o',

I spent hours on google trying to figure out the answer to this problem and finally decided to download the source and hack around with it. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround suitable for my needs (just to clarify: a script gets a string and converts it to a “permalink” URL.

My workaround consist on piping the `iconv` output to a `sed` filter:

```
echo á é ç this is a test | iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]//g'
```

The result for the above in OS X Yosemite is:

```
a e c this is a test
```

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that on your linux machine the locale is set differently...
as far as I can remember, iconv uses the current locale to translate UTF-X, and by default the macos has the locale set to "C" which (obviously) does not handle accents and language specific characters... maybe try doing this before running iconv:

```
setLocale( LC_ALL, "en_EN");
```

|K<

Comment: hi 

thank you 

but this seems not to be the problem as I have changed the locale but it has not changed anything. 

Or I don't know how to actually change the locale I am doing this in my .bash_profile 

export LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8 

and running locale returns : 

LANG= LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8" LC_ALL="fr_FR.UTF-8" 

hope this helps finding an answer

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `unaccent` which is installed by `brew install unac`:

```
$ unaccent utf-8<<<é
e
```

`unaccent` does not convert characters in decomposed form (such as `LATIN SMALL LETTER E` followed by `COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT`), but you can use `uconv` to convert characters to composed form:

```
$ unaccent utf-8<<<$'e\u0301'
é
$ uconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -x NFC<<<$'e\u0301'|unaccent utf-8
e
```

`brew install icu4c;ln -s /usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin/uconv /usr/local/bin` installs `uconv`.

Comment: Here's coparison of different std libs http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html As you can see, transliteration will work correctly only when iconv lib is based on glibc